# AWS bucket policy limitations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy, bucket

Is there any limit to number of resources we can specify in AWS bucket policy ? I got to know there is a 20 kb limit to bucket polices but is there a limit for number of resources that are allowed explicitly

Comment: No, the limit is based on size. FYI, if you are wanting to grant access to IAM entities (eg IAM Users), it is better to do this via a policy on the IAM entity itself, rather than via a Bucket Policy. What is your use-case for needing to refer to many 'resources'?

Comment: Note that you can also create access points on the S3-Bucket that essentially act as a view on the bucket, each access point can have their own "bucket policy".